# Athena SQL - Assign quarter n, n-1, n-2 and also Handle year transition

Tags: sql, amazon-athena

I'm writing SQL query for Tableau and I've encountered some problems.

Here are some backgrounds:

The data will be refreshed everyday. I want to assign tags based on quarter.
So, if CURRENT_DATE is Jul 14 , 2023, then July 3 will be classified as 'n', May 04, 2023 will be classified as 'n-1', Feb 22, 2023 will be classified as 'n-2' and Dec 25, 2022 will be classified as 'n-3'.

I will extract data for past 3 full quarters since today.

I know how to handle same year like this:

```
select 
  (CASE
            WHEN YEAR(date(date_range)) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE) AND QUARTER(date(date_range)) = QUARTER(CURRENT_DATE) THEN 'n'
            WHEN YEAR(date(date_range)) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE) AND QUARTER(date(date_range)) = QUARTER(CURRENT_DATE) - 1 THEN 'n-1'
            WHEN YEAR(date(date_range)) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE) AND QUARTER(date(date_range)) = QUARTER(CURRENT_DATE) - 2 THEN 'n-2'
            ELSE NULL -- Assign NULL for other cases
        END) AS use_for_parameter
from data_source
WHERE CAST(t.date_range AS date) >= DATE_TRUNC('quarter', 
CURRENT_DATE) - INTERVAL '9' MONTH
```

---

I've tried this to handle different year scenario but it failed .

```
select 
(CASE
            WHEN YEAR(date(date_range)) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE) AND QUARTER(date(date_range)) = QUARTER(CURRENT_DATE) THEN 'n'
            WHEN YEAR(date(date_range)) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE) AND QUARTER(date(date_range)) = QUARTER(CURRENT_DATE) - 1 THEN 'n-1'
            WHEN YEAR(date(date_range)) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE) AND QUARTER(date(date_range)) = QUARTER(CURRENT_DATE) - 2 THEN 'n-2'
            WHEN YEAR(date(date_range)) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE) - 1 AND QUARTER(date(date_range)) = 4 AND QUARTER(CURRENT_DATE) = 1 THEN 'n-3' -- Handle year transition from n to n-3
            WHEN YEAR(date(date_range)) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE) - 1 AND QUARTER(date(date_range)) = 3 AND QUARTER(CURRENT_DATE) = 1 THEN 'n-4' -- Handle year transition from n to n-4
            WHEN YEAR(date(date_range)) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE) - 1 AND QUARTER(date(date_range)) = 2 AND QUARTER(CURRENT_DATE) = 1 THEN 'n-5' -- Handle year transition from n to n-5
            ELSE NULL -- Assign NULL for other cases
        END) AS use_for_parameter
from data_source
WHERE CAST(t.date_range AS date) >= DATE_TRUNC('quarter', CURRENT_DATE) - INTERVAL '9' MONTH
```

---

Please help me to solve this problem, thank you so much!!!

Comment: `datediff('quarter', current_date, date_range)`

Comment: Thank you! I tried this but why is 2023-06-21 classified as 'n'?  CASE
     WHEN date_diff('quarter', current_date, date(date_range)) = 0 THEN 'n'
     WHEN date_diff('quarter', current_date, date(date_range)) = -1 THEN 'n-1'
     WHEN date_diff('quarter', current_date, date(date_range)) = -2 THEN 'n-2'
     WHEN date_diff('quarter', current_date, date(date_range)) = -3 THEN 'n-3'
     ELSE NULL
    END) AS use_for_parameter

Comment: Based on some digging and this documentation I thought this was the behavior you'd see: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_DATEDIFF_function.html I think you're function doesn't actually count boundaries. I don't know Athena.

Comment: Perhaps you need to try the last day of the quarter: `datediff('quarter', dateadd ('day', -1, dateadd('quarter', 1, date_trunc('quarter', current_date))), date_range) - 1`